# Supply for not yet defined power LEDs

Tags: led, dc-dc-converter, led-driver

I'm currently designing a PCB for a caving robot.
For most "main" features, I start to know quite well the precise requirements.
On one point however, there are still many unknown factor: the LEDs I will need to get decent images with the camera (that isn't chosen yet either).

So I'm a bit in a trouble to design the LED driving part of the PCB without knowing what LEDs I will need (I think I will have to try a few once the robot is nearly finished to find the right combination).

So basically, the question is how best to drive a few white LEDs without knowing the required current (probably somewhere in the 0.1-2 A range).

The requirements :

- 2 (identical) groups of LEDs, each with independent dimming from a STM32 (PWM)
- available supplies: regulated 5 V or unregulated 12 V from a Lipo 3S (i.e. 9 to 12.6 V). A small preference for the 12 V
- current : ideally up to 1-2 A per group of LEDs (2A max in total at the same time)
- efficiency shouldn't be to bad
- changing a resistor is OK
- the organisation of the LED groups can be chosen to be the most efficient (ie 1, 2 or 3 (maybe 4?) LEDs in series)

What I was thinking for now, is a DC-DC with adjustable voltage (using a potentiometer), and a N-MOS between each LEDs group and ground.
If I do so, should I still add a series resistor? If so, off how many ohms?

Or do you have any better idea?

Comment: I would buy a constant current buck boost driver with a configurable drive current and run it directly off of the battery. If you need PWM control, buy one with pwm inputs.

Comment: @user1850479 : do you mean to buy a "of the shelf module" or a corresponding IC?
In the first case, I'd rather avoid, because of very limited space on the robot and to avoid the additional wiring : the circuit should be part of the PCB.

In the second cas, it might be an option, even if it means using 2 such circuits (one per group of Leds)

Comment: I recommend buying a module for this. If you want it to go on an existing board, buy an SMD module and solder it to your board. This is probably going to be at least as compact as anything you're going to design and it will be much easier. Design your own if you can't find something that meets your spec (e.g. weird voltage, etc).

Comment: Is it 0.1A or 1A at the bottom end? You say both.

Comment: @Passerby : that's the problem : I have no idea yet how much light I will need to get "decent" images, so I have no idea how much current I will need. But as I'm hopping to stay with the same PCB (it will already be quite expensive, so I'd rather not have to order it a second time if I can avoid), I have to overdesign it now, to be sure it will work whatever LEDs I chose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use PWM on the LEDs, and the camera has a rolling shutter (they pretty much all do) then there is a risk of visible flicker in your video. This is due to the interaction of the rolling shutter sampling different parts of the image at different time, and the LEDs blinking at the PWM frequency. So you can get dark/light stripes or the whole image "blinking", depending on the beat frequency between PWM and shutter.

There are two ways around this: either use a high PWM frequency, above 25kHz, or use constant current drive with analog dimming. Both have pros and cons.

High frequency PWM:

Pros: Simple, only one MOSFET per output. LED CCT (color temperature) depends on current: with PWM there is no CCT variation since the current is always the same when it's on.

Cons: needs a fast clock to have enough bits to get useful dimming at low levels. Say you have a 48MHz clock on your STM32, then you use 10 bit PWM, round that to 1000 levels to get a 48kHz PWM. If you don't need accuracy at low levels, you can use 8 bit PWM and go even faster. Make sure there is enough gate drive current to switch the MOSFET properly at this frequency. For example you can use a 74ACT logic chip to convert 3V3 to 5V and drive the gates with about 20mA.

Analog dimming:

Pros: the smoothest, most constant light output.

Cons: more complicated, you need one buck driver per light, and analog dimming at low power runs into issues with offset voltage in the current sense amp. Since current is variable, you get CCT change. Efficiency will be higher, since there is no resistor. Also LED efficiency decreases at high current, so analog dimming gives better efficiency at low current.

Also think about the optics! For your caving robot, you'll probably want at least two lights, one with a narrow beam and one with a wide beam. I'm mentioning optics because that has an important influence on the number of LEDs, which in turn determines how you will drive them.

If you want a tight beam to see far away, then you'll need tight beam optics, which usually accomodate only one LED. But then, if it is tight, then it is useless if it's not pointing in the right direction. Perhaps you need a motor to aim it? (it gets annoying, unless you already have a swivel mount for the camera).

If you use a wide beam, then stuff in the foreground will get too much light, and stuff in the background won't get enough. This is also annoying, if the robot is in a tunnel, the walls near it will be overexposed, while the tunnel further away will be black.

So here's an idea: why not use a virtual swivel mount? I mean, a number of tight-ish lenses, like 10°, spread in an arc, each with one LED, being PWM'ed  individually. So the light can be aimed without moving parts.

Basically, what I'm telling you is make the lighting modular. Don't freeze the design on your PCB, because if later you realize it doesn't work the way you want it, you'll be stuck with it. There are so many LED optics to choose from. So, route a bunch of PWMs and an I2C port to a connector, and put the lighting driver on a separate board. You can experiment with it and develop it in your office at night, see how the camera reacts to it, etc. In fact, you can prototype the light and optics with a bench power supply driving the LEDs.

Now for the hardware solutions:

If you want a low number of channels with analog dimming, you can use a buck LED driver chip like [this one](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL8843Q.pdf), per channel. There are many available in the automotive LED driver market segment that fit your voltage and current needs. Efficiency will be pretty high if you use 3 LEDs in series ; for less LEDs the buck diode will eat a significant part of the output voltage and it's no longer that efficient.

If you want many channels then the simplest is a constant voltage output buck fed from your battery, with PWM MOSFETs and resistors. Since you'll be using all identical LEDs for color matching, they should have close enough Vf that you can use a buck output voltage close to that, and a lowish resistor value.  But of course, all your LED strings need the same number of LEDs, otherwise you'll have to waste a lot of voltage on the resistors.

A temperature sensor on the LED heatsink is recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I was indeed planning on placing at least a 1D lidar, and maybe the camera as well on a servo. I might add the LEDs on it.

For the wide + spot light, it is indeed a good idea (specialy as this robot is intended for cracks, to very narrow left/right, and far biger in front and up/down.

So external PCB seems indeed an interesting solution (even if it requires some extra wiring). At least, it should be simple enough to do the assembly myself. I will check if I have enough PWM outputs left to do PWM control, if not, I'm going to I2C

Comment: If the robot is always in the same direction in the crack, there are optics with different horizontal and vertical dispersion, could be useful. Here's a [10°x50°](https://www.lumitronix.com/en_gb/ledil-lens-21-6x21-6mm-for-nichia-n36-10x50-60225.html), they're available for many different LEDs.

Comment: yes, the robot will always be oriented the same way compared to the crack : so optics like those from your link are indeed a good idea

Comment: I used that for a bicycle light: tight beam lens for long distance, but it doesn't light the pothole right in front of the wheel. Then a wide asymmetric lens aimed down to light both in front of the wheel and to the sides, but not in the face of the guy coming in the other direction. It was extremely fiddly to set up.